# How can I input a state to a variable of enum type in C++?

Tags: c++, enums, std

```
#include <iostream>
enum Day { Mon = 1, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun };
void printa(Day day);
int main() {
    enum Day day = Sun;
    printa(day);

    return 0;
}
void printa(Day day) {
    if (day > Fri)
        std::cout << "weekend" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "weekdays" << std::endl;
}
```

See above code.

Day is defined as a variable of type enum.

The value of “Sun” is allocated to day, which is 7.

So as a result, "weekend" is printed.

Now I want this: I input a value (from 1 to 7) to day, that is, give it a state.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
enum Day { Mon = 1, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun };
void printa(Day day);
int main() {
    enum Day day = Sun;
    std::cin >> day; // Here is the added line
    printa(day);

    return 0;
}
void printa(Day day) {
    if (day > Fri)
        std::cout << "weekend" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "weekdays" << std::endl;
}
```

It can't work.

**Can anybody tell me why?**

**How can I input a state to a variable of  enum type in C++  ?**

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Spend weeks in reading a [good book on C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/). See also some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-input-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019

Comment: For C, read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) standard. For C++, see also [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the C++11 standard

Comment: Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler. With [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: There isn't an implicit mapping from `int` to an enumerated type, or vice versa.  Some folks suggest casting `int` to the `enum` but I don't.   A simple technique I've seen a few times (in both C and C++, since you've tagged both) is to read an integral value, and then a simple conditional construct (e.g. using a `switch`) to map the integral value to the enumerated type. Another approach (C++ specific) is using `std::map<int, your_enum>`.    An advantage of a map is that you can adapt it to any type of input  (e.g. mapping strings like `"Monday"` or `"Mon"` to the enumerated value `Mon`).

Comment: "It can't work" is not a specific problem or error.

Comment: I don't see any C code here. In C enums **are integer types.**

Comment: @Peter the mapping of enum to to string, which can be done through an array for enums with small values, and the corresponding mapping of string to enum are one of the few cases where defines are useful and legitimate. Something like


`std::map<std::string, Day> eMap;
const char *eArr[7];
#define ADD_ENUM(e) \
do { \
 eMap[#e] = e; \
 eArr[e] = #e; } \
while(false)

// ...

ADD_ENUM(Monday);`

Comment: As an aside, this is where a language with reflection like C# shines and C++ feels like the stone age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use cin direct to enum type, but you can do it to an int and static cast it to your enum type like shown below:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Day : uint16_t { Mon = 1, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun };

void printa(Day day) {
     if (day > Fri)
        std::cout << "weekend" << std::endl;
     else
        std::cout << "weekdays" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    uint16_t day = Sun;

    std::cin >> day;

    printa(static_cast<Day>(day));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SleepingOnAGiant'SShoulder This is probably the best solution, you'll find. However, keep in mind, that you can not pass a string like "Sun" or "Mon" to stdin here, because stdin doesn't know your enum type. So you'll need to pass an int from 1 to 7. If you want to pass something like "Sun" to stdin, I think you'll have to do some kind of remapping to your enum type anfter the `std::cin`.